# React function not defined

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react, I am trying to call an function ,
Here is my code:

```
import React,{useState} from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios"
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
const Register = prop => {
  const [username, setusername] = useState([]);
handleChange = () => {
  return "Hello World!";
}
  return (
    <>
  
            <Form role="form">
<FormGroup className="has-success">
                <InputGroup className="input-group-alternative mb-3">
                  <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                    <InputGroupText>
                      <i className="ni ni-hat-3" />
                    </InputGroupText>
                  </InputGroupAddon>
                  <Input
                  className="form-control-alternative is-valid"
                    placeholder="User Name"
                    type="text" 
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    id="input-username" 
                  />
                </InputGroup>
              </FormGroup>"text-center">
                <Button className="mt-4" color="primary" type="button">
                  Create account
                </Button>
              </div>
            </Form>
          
       
    </>
  );
};

export default Register;
```

i am trying to setstates on change function , but i am facing an error "handleChange not defined"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define handleChange function like this

```
 const handleChange = () => {
    return "Hello World!";
 };
```

Or

```
function handleChange(){
    return "Hello World!";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the function, as for now you assigning the function to a variable named `handleChange`, which does not exists in current scope.

```
const Register = (prop) => {
  // add const beforehand
  const handleChange = () => {...};
  return <>...</>;
};
```